# Detect when an axis is on some point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game where I have a door that rotates 90 degrees. When the door rotates I want something to happen when the transform.rotation is (0 ,0 , 30), so basically when it has rotated 30 degress on the z-axis. I've tried some stuff, but this is how i've come so far.

```
public GameObject door;

private void Update()
    {
       if(door.transform.rotation.z == 30)
        {
            ///Do something
        }
    }
```

Like I said earlier, I want something to happen when the door has rotated 30 degrees.

Nothing happens when i use this code.

Comment: Can you describe the expected results vs actual results?

Comment: Consider using a comparison technique appropriate for floating point numbers:  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Epsilon.html

Comment: @Wyck Nothing happens.

Comment: transform.rotation is a quaternion, and doesn't use a unit of degrees. You will want to get the rotation as euler angles with a Mathf.Approximately if you want to compare with a degree value.

Answer (score 1):

1) transform.rotation is not using degree, use eulerAngles.

2) when you want to compare float values , its never equal (approximatives values), so you could test  if the value belongs to an interval (or use Mathf.Approximately, but its the same thing):

```
   if(door.transform.eulerAngles.z > 29 && door.transform.eulerAngles.z < 31)
    {
        ///Do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try output 'door.transform.rotation.z' to see what is this value. Probably, it is between 0.0 and 1.0